# VSTS Load Testing - How to read runsettings dynamically of currently running load test file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing

I am running a load test from some xxx.loadtest file and would like read the active run settings section of this xxx.loadtest load test file dynamically for various properties such as Description, Test Iterations, Run Duration etc. Please note that the file name xxx.loadtest keep on changing as I run different set of load tests. So I cannot hardcode that in my code. Is there a easy way to get the full file path of this load test file without having to hardcode the file name ?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If not then please [edit] it to make it clearer. If it has been answered then please read about [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Many of the values in the run settings are available via a load test plugin, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ms243153(v=vs.110)) for more about creating them. The code below is an extract from a plugin I wrote, it shows how to access two of the values in the run settings.

```
public class LoadTestPluginExample : ILoadTestPlugin
{
    private LoadTest m_loadTest;

    private int warmUpPlusRunDuration;

    public void Initialize(LoadTest loadTest)
    {
        m_loadTest = loadTest;

        warmUpPlusRunDuration = m_loadTest.RunSettings.WarmupTime + m_loadTest.RunSettings.RunDuration;
    }

    ... other plugin methods that use warmUpPlusRunDuration
}
```

I regularly use the [intelisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2017) of Visual Studio to explore the values etc that are available in web tests and in load tests.

If you really want to read the `.loadtest` file itself then the original full filename and file path are probably not available at run time, because the load test is deployed to the execution computer(s). As the original and execution computers may be different then the original path may not be valid during the execution. However, I believe (but I cannot check at the moment) that the `.loadtest` file is deployed into the (by default) `...\TestResults\{{name+date+time}}\...` folders along with the other files for the test. One of those folders is the current directory when the test runs so it should be simple to do a search for `.loadtest` files in the relevant directory.

The [number of agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.loadtesting.loadtestcontext.agentcount?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_LoadTesting_LoadTestContext_AgentCount) is available in the `AgentCount` property from the `LoadTestContext` and it is one of the named entries the context of a web test when it is executed as part of a load test. That means it can only be accessed via the code of a plugin (or similar) and makes debugging and testing the plugin harder as the `LoadTestContext` is only available within a load test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AdrianHHH. I am already using load test plugin. Along with the parameters mentioned,I mainly need the Agent Count (Total Cores) parameter. I will be using below code snippet to read loadtest file that is automatically deployed in .\Out folder

 `string[] totalLoadTestFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory, ".loadtest", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);`